# Pack int in a string

Tags: python, c++, pack

I am trying to translate this sequence from Python to C++.

```
bytesString = struct.pack('!l', value)
```

How can I pack an integer value into a std::string using byte shifts?

Comment: I attempted to use byte shifts to store values in a char array like buffer[i] = (val >> 8) & 0xff

Answer (score 4):

#### Easy-to-maintain method (not endian-agnostic)

The typical method of "encoding" a value of a primitive type into a byte sequence is with a simple `std::copy`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename T>
std::string pack(const T val)
{
   std::string bytes(sizeof(T), '\0');
   std::copy(
      reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&val),
      reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&val) + sizeof(T),
      bytes.begin()
   );
   return bytes;
}

int main()
{
   int x = 42;
   std::string bytes{pack(x)};

   std::cout << std::noshowbase << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
   for (auto c : bytes)
      std::cout << "0x" << std::setw(2) << +c << ' ';

   // ^ may need tweaking for values above 127; not sure
}

// On my little-endian system with 32-bit int:
//  "0x2a 0x00 0x00 0x00"
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12fa8ec6ecd41403))

Probably requires C++11 to be strict, as `std::string` wasn't formally contiguous before that. I've obviously used C++11 syntax in `main`, but that can be trivially changed.

---

#### Easy-to-maintain method (network byte order)

If you want the result to always be in network byte order (which matches the use of `!` in your Python expression), you could apply `htonl` first:

```
std::string bytes{pack(htonl(x))};
```

*(Solutions that simply `reinterpret_cast` the whole value (rather than copying) have potential alignment and aliasing problems.)*

---

#### Optimal method (network byte order)

If your code is in a tight loop and you don't want the endianness conversion *and* the copy, then you may consider a loop over shifts:

```
#include <string>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename T>
std::string pack_in_network_order(const T val)
{
   const size_t NBYTES = sizeof(T);
   std::string bytes(NBYTES, '\0');

   for (size_t i = 0; i < NBYTES; i++)
      bytes[NBYTES - 1 - i] = (val >> (i * CHAR_BIT)) & 0xFF;

   return bytes;
}

int main()
{
   int x = 42;
   std::string bytes{pack_in_network_order(x)};

   std::cout << std::noshowbase << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
   for (auto c : bytes)
      std::cout << "0x" << std::setw(2) << +c << ' ';
}

// On my system with 32-bit int:
//  "0x00 0x00 0x00 0x2a"
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0340c32b27670b1))

*(I've used `CHAR_BIT` for portability but hard-coded `0xFF` as the value mask. You'll want to fix that.)*